# Gson toJson method includes escape character when printing Strings

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using Gson to convert a Java object to Json. One of the object's fields holds a string containing an escaped double quote, like this:

```
"double quote:'\"'"
```

The toJson method returns the string as above, but I would like to print this instead:

```
double quote:'"'
```

Is this possible using Gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? The surrounding quotes and the escape character are mandatory in JS/JSON as well.

The following JS piece just shows the correct value:

```
var json = { test: "double quote:'\"'" };
alert(json.test);
```

Don't print it using `System.out.println()` or so, Java doesn't parse JSON, only JS does that ;)

Comment: I'm passing the JSON onto an Ext grid (via JSP) and it doesn't seem to like the escape characters.

Comment: Apparently you passed it the wrong way. E.g. `var foo = ${jsonFromServer};` should do (no quotes). If you're using JSTL `c:out`, ensure that its `escapeXml` attribute is set to `false`.